# Good rating plugin that doesn't depend on an external service?

Tags: plugins, rating

Is there a good plugin for rating blog posts that doesn't depend on PollDaddy or another external service? Ideally I'd like a plugin similar in appearance to [Polldaddy Polls & Ratings](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/polldaddy/), but without the PollDaddy dependency (I'd prefer to have the rating data in the WP database).

*EDIT: just to make things clear: I'm not interested in polls, only in rating for blog posts*

---

What I tried so far:

- [GD Star rating](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gd-star-rating/): too complex, and doesn't work at all for me (*)
- [WP-PostRatings](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-postratings/): <strike>doesn't work at all for me (*)</strike> *(my mistake... I didn't realize I had to modify the theme. This one works fine)*
- [kk Star ratings](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/kk-star-ratings/): doesn't look too good with my theme (Garland revisited)
- [Post ratings](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post-ratings/): simple, good looking, but there's a bug with my theme; <strike>I'll try to fix the CSS if I can't find anything better</strike> *(OK, I'm really, really bad at CSS...)*
- [Rating-Widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rating-widget/): really nice, but depends on external site

*(*) perhaps this is because I have an unusual setup (Windows/IIS server, SQL Server database with WP database abstraction plugin, multi-site with domain mapping)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually used [WP-PostRatings](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-postratings/). I thought it wasn't working, but actually I just needed to edit the theme to insert the rating where I wanted it.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [WP Survey and Quiz Tool](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-survey-and-quiz-tool/) before with good success and can recommend that to you.

Comment: Thanks, but this it not what I'm looking for... I want a plugin for rating blog posts (e.g. 1 to 5 stars, thumb up/thumb down...), not for creating polls